# How to upload encrypted image files in django

Tags: django, image, forms, upload, models

This is my first time working in django and I have no idea how models and forms work. I have read and followed a lot of tutorials but nothing has worked. Could someone properly guide me through this process. I want to upload a file and have a record of which user has uploaded the file. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Upload(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="files")
    date_upload = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from app_name.models import Upload

class UploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Upload
```

views.py

```
def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/url/')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render_to_response('upload.html', {'form': form})
```

upload.html

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload/" name="test" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <input type="submit" value="Save File">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks so much Catherine, but I get "NameError: name 'User' is not defined" when I go runserver

Comment: That's because you need to import the User model.
`from django.contrib.auth.models import User`